# Pointer or No Pointer for Golang Struct to reference other struct and Why

Tags: pointers, go, struct

I have read some of the stack overflow question related to "**why pointer and why not pointer**", but I could not understand much.

So, I thought to understand and learn based on my situation on `golang` perspective.

I have 2 struct

```
type Discussion struct {
    ID      string `json:"id"`
    Title   string `json:"title"`
    Content string `json:"content"`
    Owner   *User  `json:"owner"`
}

type User struct {
    ID   string `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

In above `Discussion` struct you can see, I used `*User` for `Owner` field.

Considering situation, I do not have to change data for `Owner` after creating value for `Discussion` like below, should I use only `User` or it's better to use `*User` like below

```
func main() {
    u := User {
        ID: "2",
        Name: "StackOverflow",
    }
    d := Discussion{
        ID: "1",
        Title: "This is my family",
        Content: "I love my family",
        Owner: &u,
    }
}
```

**or, Should I use like below -**

```
type Discussion struct {
    ID      string `json:"id"`
    Title   string `json:"title"`
    Content string `json:"content"`
    Owner   User   `json:"owner"`
}

type User struct {
    ID   string `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    u := User {
        ID: "2",
        Name: "StackOverflow",
    }
    d := Discussion{
        ID: "1",
        Title: "This is my family",
        Content: "I love my family",
        Owner: u,
    }
}
```

I have following question based on above 2 situation

1. Performance - which one is better & why?
2. Garbage Collection - which one is better & why?
3. Any Memory effects?
4. Any other effects!

**Which one should be used on above example and why?**

## **Please put your answer only based on above example**, which method would you have choosed above and why?

Thanks

Comment: They *do completely different things*, and they only look the same in trivial examples. So you should choose the one that does what you want, not based on performance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate `they do completely different things`, I want to learn and know them, or if you can provide any reference URL, where I can know more about it based on my situation above or anything nearby. That will be great help. Thanks

Comment: Neither one is "better" than the other, they're different.

Comment: any source or reference to learn more about it, why it's different based on golang perspective.

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1 ff